# How do I import 'umap' package in python?

Tags: python, import

After install 'umap' package, I can't import

I tried reinstall pre version (1.3.10, 1.4.0rc1).
But, It's not working

How can I do?

```
!pip3 install umap-learn
!pip3 install umap-learn[plot]
import umap
```

This is the error I get:

> No module named 'umap'

Answer (score 3):

you probably confused umap and umap-learn libs,

if that's the case, the code below'll solve your problem

https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_usage.html

```
pip uninstall umap

pip install umap-learn

import umap.umap_ as umap
reducer = umap.UMAP()
```